# getting NULL in sql table while parsing xml in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse an XML document with a query.

Here is a sample of my XML:

```
<export xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://bbhgtm.gov.com/oos/export/1" xmlns:oos="http://bbhgtm.gov.com/oos/types/1">
  <notificationOK>
    <oos:id>8373125</oos:id>
    <oos:notificationNumber>0173200001513000422</oos:notificationNumber>
```

Here is my query

```
declare @hdoc int

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @x,

'
<export xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:q="http://bbhgtm.gov.com/oos/export/1" 
xmlns:oos="http://bbhgtm.gov.com/oos/types/1"/>

'


select *
from openxml(@hdoc, '/notificationOK/oos:id/oos:notificationNumber/', 1)
WITH(
      versionNumber int 'oos:versionNumber'
      ,createDate datetime 'oos:createDate'
      )

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc
```

But I'm getting NULL in my SQL table.

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're **ignoring** the XML namespaces on your XML document!

```
<export xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns="http://bbhgtm.gov.com/oos/export/1" 
        xmlns:oos="http://bbhgtm.gov.com/oos/types/1">
```

See those `xmlns=.....` and `xmlns:oos=......` attributes? Those define **XML namespaces** that need to be taken into account when querying!

Also, I'd recommend to use the **built-in, native** XQuery support rather than the clumsy `OPENXML` code.

Try this code here:

```
DECLARE @input XML = 
    '<export xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xmlns="http://bbhgtm.gov.com/oos/export/1" 
             xmlns:oos="http://bbhgtm.gov.com/oos/types/1">
         <notificationOK>
             <oos:id>8373125</oos:id>
             <oos:notificationNumber>0173200001513000422</oos:notificationNumber>
         </notificationOK>
     </export>'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://bbhgtm.gov.com/oos/types/1' AS oos, 
                    DEFAULT 'http://bbhgtm.gov.com/oos/export/1')
SELECT
    id = XC.value('(oos:id)[1]', 'int'),
    NotificationNumber = XC.value('(oos:notificationNumber)[1]', 'bigint')
FROM
    @input.nodes('/export/notificationOK') AS XT(XC)
```

This results in an output something like this:

[image]

Comment: spot on!!. Was thinking for a long time

Comment: Great)! Works! But ,just theoretically, how can I use this to parce multiple xml files in sql table? Or better use SSIS? Just point me a direction ...

Comment: @ArtemVaskanyan: load those XML files into an XML variable - one by one - and then apply this XQuery to them to get the data contained in those XML files